# How to loop through a file based on conditions

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file with following contents. File name is "myXLog.txt":

```
IAAS Session factory creation started

X

Y

z

Communications link failure
```

What I want is to read the file and if a string "IAAS Session factory creation started" is found then continue reading and if another string "Communications link failure" is found then return a message. My code only gets the first line and does not go further. Please help I checked a lot of help on internet but could not manage as I am new to shell scripting (very new).`

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="myXLog.txt"    
while read line
do

if [[ $line == "IAAS Session factory creation started" ]] ; then
       a="YES"
       echo $a
       if a="YES"; then #HERE I WANT TO CONTINUE READING BUT NOT SURE HOW
       if [[ $line == "Communications link failure" ]] ; then
            echo "ERROR"

       else echo "ALL IS WELL"      $line
       fi
       fi
else echo "BYE"
    #fi
fi
done < $filename
```

This only prints

YES

ALL IS WELL IAAS Session factory creation started

BYE

BYE

BYE

BYE

Comment: After you found the *IASS* string, you look at the immediately following line, and output ERROR only if **this** line has the failure text. My guess is that your input file doesn't have these two lines in immediate succession.

Comment: Yes they are not in immediate succession and that is the problem. I an at max read the immediate next line, but unable to read further. And the log will never ever contain error condition immediately next to IAAS line

Comment: To be more clear, I want to continue reading unless the error criteria is met

Comment: Well, if there are several lines in between, why then are you checking exactly the next line? I don't quite understand the logic of your script.

Comment: Actually "read line" I think may be used for immediate next line, my question is how do I keep on reading, what is the syntax and the commands. Pardon my mistakes for now, I am new to this.

Comment: You could use a variable, which contains the information, whether the first string has been found already. Depending on the content of this variable, you search either the first or the second string.

Comment: BTW, what's the point in clearing `IFS`?

Comment: I can at max read the immediate next line, but not sure how to keep on reading

Comment: You have an example in your own script of reading multiple lines; just use a loop.  You should probably step back and fully describe the problem you are trying to solve.  What do you want to do if the file contains neither string?  What if it only contains the 'creation started' line?  In those cases, do you simply output nothing?  If so, why are you writing "BYE" for each line of your file?  Is that merely a debug statement?  Describe the problem accurately.

Comment: @WilliamPursell   ...yes BYE and all are just debug statements. What I want here is : """if the first line "IAAS Session factory creation started" is found, then continue reading till it find a line like "Communications link failure", and once that met return something

Comment: @user1934428 I have changed the code now, I am searching over net and coding that is it. Changed it now (removed the IFS). Apologies for the confusion

Comment: What do you mean by "return something"?   Do you literally mean "print something and exit"?  Or do you want to continue processing data in the file.  If the footer doesn't exist, do you just exit without doing anything?  What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Are you merely trying to skip over all the lines between the header and the footer?

Comment: @RahulMukherjee : Your code doesn't make much sense: You are setting the variable *a* to YES, and immediately after try to ask, whether the variable has the value YES. Aktually, the way of querying this is incorrect (it would be `if [[ $a == YES ]]`), but even if you wrote it in the correct way, the outcome would be, of course, always true!

Comment: @RahulMukherjee : It would also help if you would tell us your general experience in programming. You said that you don't have experience, but I get the impression that you don't have any programming experience so far. If this is correct, it would be better if you would say so, because the responses you get, would then be maybe less technical. OTOH, if you have experience in a different programming language (for instance Awk, Perl or Ruby), the problem would maybe much easier to solve in one of these).

Comment: @user1934428 I am a Progress 4GL developer, Apache Spark developer, with SCALA knowledge mainly. Also did C#.NET quite a few years ago. The impression you got may be due to the fact that I am starting my Shell Scripting works now and that too this is a program with which I have started and that too due too company timelines and ad-hoc deliverable :) . Hope I will someday nullify this "you don't have any programming experience" statement :) . Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1):

I think if you stop nesting your conditions, this will work. You basically want to test "if I've seen the 'start' line and the current line is the 'end' line, print something and [break out of the loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html)". At present, the code is only checking for the error message while it's *on the same line* as when it finds the "start" message, which will never be true, since the line can either be the start or the end message, but not both at the same time. Instead, you want to track "have I seen the start message" in a variable *outside* of the loop (well, it could be inside, since Bash defaults to global variables, but putting it outside makes things much easier to understand), set that variable when you see the "start" line, and then on every subsequent line, check for the error *and* the "found start" variable.

I think the following code would likely do the trick. There are many shorter ways to do this, but this one is the easiest (for me) to understand:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="myXLog.txt"
found=""
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "IAAS Session factory creation started" ]]; then
        echo "START: $line"
        found="start"
    # This tests: "Have we found the start line, and is the line the error message?"
    elif [[ $found == "start" && $line == "Communications link failure" ]]; then
        found="error"
        echo "ERROR: $line"
        break
    elif [[ $found == "start" ]]; then
        echo "ALL IS WELL: $line"
    fi
    # Implicit else: if we have not yet seen the 'started' line, do nothing.
done < $filename
```

After that loop ran, you could check the value of the `$found` variable to see if it got to the end of the file without seeing an error, e.g.:

```
# Check if $found is empty.
if [[ -z $found ]]; then
    echo "Never found a 'started' line!"
elif [[ $found == "start" ]]; then
    echo "Found a 'started' line and no errors; finished reading the file!"
else # $found is "error"
    echo "Stopped reading after an error!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start. You are checking to see if the line you are currently reading is the start to your message (`"IAAS Session factory creation started"`) and you set a variable `a` to flag that you have found it! That's perfect.

You are looping here, so it will execute everything inside that `if` block and the `while; do` will LOOP to the next line and try that SAME `if` block again. Of course your current line isn't `"IAAS Session factory creation started"` anymore so it will head to your `else` and print `"bye"`.

Instead you want to check if your `a` variable is set to `YES` and perform some other action in your current iteration of the file. You will do that with an `elif` (Else If). We can also use an `elif` to test if we hit the end of the message `"Communications link failure"`

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="myXLog.txt"    
while read line
do    
  if [[ $line == "IAAS Session factory creation started" ]] ; then
    a="YES"
    echo $a
  elif [[ $a == "YES" ]; then 
    echo "ALL IS WELL" $line     
  elif [[ $line == "Communications link failure" ]] ; then
    echo "ERROR"
  else 
    echo "BYE"    
  fi
done < $filename
```

Comment: I think this is missing a "break" after the ERROR print. The question wanted a message "returned" after an error matching a start line, so there's no reason to keep reading. It might be fine on small files, but could bog down on ones that have a lot of data after the error.

Comment: @ZacB I totally agree. I think there are a lot of ways I would go about improving this code (I would probably just do a quick awk script instead, honestly). I think the big takeaway for OP though is that 1) The stuff inside the While;Do loop is executed for each line and 2) `elif` as a concept. Totally agree though. OP, break out of your loop when you hit your `Communications Link Failure` condition to stop reading the file.